# Unable to count the rows returned by a query containing OPTION(MAXRECURSION) as sub-query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
Select count(*) 
from 
    (
        Select  name  
        from
            (
                Select name,address  
                from <table_name>
            ) ANS 
            OPTION(MAXRECURSION 1)
    ) a1
```

Error on executing the query:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'OPTION'

Comment: Where is your table name ?

Comment: Try running parts of your querry to find out which is wrong. Start with  Select name,address from (that seems wrong), then Select name from( Select name,address from ) and so on. Btw, I don't think ANS is valid SQL, you're missing table names and Select name from( Select name,address from tablename) can be reduced to Select name tablename.

Comment: You do not have a recursive cte - so what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: My query was about the syntax error, table name can be placed at <table_name> in the query. The issue is however resolved now,by fetching count using the result set. Thanks for your responses.

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the `OPTION(MAXRECURSION ...)` from the subquery to the end of the main query.

```
Select count(*) 
from 
    (
        Select name 
        from
            (
                Select name,address 
                from <table_name>
            ) ANS 
    ) a1
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 1);
```

Comment: OPTION(MAXRECURSION 1) has to be put while fetching the name and address i.e. in the inner query. If it is placed at the end of the main query,its meaning would change.